# Google Play Unofficial API Login Error

Tags: android, python, api, google-play, apk

I'm Trying to download a list of android APKs to my computer, in order to do so I would like to use GooglePlay API with Python.
I have saved the library ([github link](https://github.com/egirault/googleplay-api)) and followed the instructions (wrote my login credentials and android ID to the file `config.py`).

The API didn't work no matter what credentials I have entered. Then I found [this link](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/45229904-valueerror-too-many-values-to-unpack-how-to-fix-it%20/%22this%20link%22) and followed it.
At first, I wanted to search for an APP in the market, running the following command worked fine and returned the output below:

> `>python search.py "angry birds"`
>   C:\python27\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:852: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
>     InsecureRequestWarning)
>   C:\python27\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:852: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
>     InsecureRequestWarning)
>   Title;Package name;Creator;Super Dev;Price;Offer Type;Version Code;Size;Rating;Num Downloads
>   Angry Birds;com.rovio.angrybirds;Rovio Entertainment Ltd.;0;Free;1;22574001;99.5MB;4.39;100,000,000+
>   Angry Birds Star Wars;com.rovio.angrybirdsstarwars.ads.iap;Rovio Entertainment Ltd.;0;Free;1;151100;47.7MB;4.34;100,000,000+
>   Angry Birds Rio;com.rovio.angrybirdsrio;Rovio Entertainment Ltd.;0;Free;1;2661;47.5MB;4.37;100,000,000+
>   Angry Birds Epic RPG;com.rovio.gold;Rovio Entertainment Ltd.;0;Free;1;4244;275.5MB;4.50;10,000,000+
>   Angry Birds Go!;com.rovio.angrybirdsgo;Rovio Entertainment Ltd.;0;Free;1;20612;421.4MB;4.24;50,000,000+
>   Angry Birds Star Wars II Free;com.rovio.angrybirdsstarwarsii.ads;Rovio Entertainment Ltd.;0;Free;1;192200;54.1MB;4.31;50,000,000+
>   Angry Birds Seasons;com.rovio.angrybirdsseasons;Rovio Entertainment Ltd.;0;Free;1;6610;99.7MB;4.35;100,000,000+
>   Bad Piggies HD;com.rovio.BadPiggiesHD;Rovio Entertainment Ltd.;0;Free;1;2330;65.7MB;4.32;10,000,000+
>   Angry Birds Friends;com.rovio.angrybirdsfriends;Rovio Entertainment Ltd.;0;Free;1;12907;48.5MB;4.22;50,000,000+
>   Angry Birds Space;com.rovio.angrybirdsspace.ads;Rovio Entertainment Ltd.;0;Free;1;221200;48.8MB;4.36;100,000,000+

running the exact same command again returned:

> `>python search.py "angry birds"`
>   C:\python27\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:852: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
>     InsecureRequestWarning)
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>        File "search.py", line 30, in 
>       api.login(GOOGLE_LOGIN, GOOGLE_PASSWORD, AUTH_TOKEN)
>     File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\googleplay-api-master\googleplay.py", line 138, in login
>       raise LoginError("server says: " + params["error"])
>   googleplay.LoginError: u'server says: BadAuthentication'

And of course, the login also failed when I have tried to download an APP.

I have tried to solve this problem for pretty long time and I really need a solution.
Where did I go wrong ? 
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: *Where did I go wrong ?* you are using not existing api.

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! How is it possible that it worked fine for the first query? What is the correct way to do it ? I have tried several API's and nothing worked for me :(

Comment: You need to analyse the code... Or fill the issue on github and wait till programmer of this solution will fix it.

Comment: There is an opened issue for the same problem (posted 15 days ago), meanwhile, Do you know about working API/other way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of tries, Found two solutions:
 1. When trying to run the same download command over and over again the download works partially, I wrote a script that tries 100 times to download each file and I get a very good success ratio.
 2. Seems that working with AUTH token as can be created with [Token-dispenser](https://github.com/yeriomin/token-dispenser) instead of the regular google play credentials actually works much better. For more information - see the following [Issue](https://github.com/egirault/googleplay-api/issues/74)